# "Flicker" what does this word mean in the video?

Tags: word-meaning, slang

I am so afraid that I am bombarding lots of questions here.

And let me thank you so much for all ( probably ) of native speakers here for your efforts from the bottom of my heart.

I like(d) Kee&Peele. Since my job is related with the education. I can't stand until I get the finest answer ( or correct answer ), about which I probably apologize.

Now. onto the [Kee&Peele's sketche](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1t24XAntNCY).

I am afraid even though I was watching the English title. I was not able to understand what the "Flicker" means.

Could the word be fallen into [one of the categories in the urban dictionary?](https://www.azdictionary.com/urban-dictionary/definition/flicker)

Or is it else?

In the last scene, **Gabe** tells "He flicked me". But I can not understand yet. ( together with the schmutz stuff ).

I sincerely appreciate your help. Thank you beforehand in advance.

---

Thank you for your answer user3932000 and Jim at the comment.

It's kind of hard to get the meaning of verbs etc that mostly only native speakers know.

Comment: "Flicker" has another meaning when it comes to video, just in case you come across it in another context.  It means rapid and cyclical flashing or brightening/dimming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means "person who flicks." It's a common prank that ends with the person "flicking" their finger up at the other person's face. I tried to explain it with words, but a video demonstrates it much better: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ElUa5osLkZQ)